# TypeError: undefined is not a function when triggering AJAX requests in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, angularjs

I followed tutorial on this [LINK](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/832288/CRUD-with-SPA-ASP-NET-Web-API-and-Angular-js) to create AJAX requests on my angularJS appliction (CRUD operations). After I finished coding I tried to perform AJAX request (get all data from database) but when I lunch my application I got this error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at new <anonymous> (http://localhost:49510/Scripts/application/controllers.js:4:15)
```

Does someone knows where's the problem and how to fix it?

Here is code:

controller:

```
app.controller('ContactsController', [
    '$scope', '$http', '$location', 'contactsService',
    function ($scope, $location, $http, contactsService) {
        $http.get('/contacts/').success(function (data) { //triggers error
            alert(data);
            $scope.contact = data;
            $scope.loading = false;
        })
        .error(function () {
            alert ("An Error has occured while loading contacts!");
           // $scope.loading = false;
        });
        $scope.editContact = function (id) {
            $location.path('/edit-contact/' + id);
        };

        $scope.displayContact = function (id) {
            $location.path('/display-contact/' + id);
        };


        $scope.showDetails = function (id) {
            var el = angular.element(document.getElementById('#ct-details-' + id));
            el.toggleClass('details-hidden');
        }

    }
]);
```

and here is contacts.html template:

```
<div class="container view">
    <header>
        <h3>Contacts</h3>
    </header>

    <div>
        <a class="nav-pills hover" href="#/add-contact">Add Contact</a>
    </div>
    <br /><br />

    <div class="row">
        <ul class="span5" >
            <li class="nav-pills nav-stacked contact-row" data-ng-repeat="contact in contacts | orderBy:'firstName'">
                <span id="ct-details-{{contact.id}}" data-ng-click="displayContact(contact.id)" style="cursor:pointer;" class="contact-data details-hidden" href="" >
                    <span class="span3 contact-name" >{{contact.firstName + ' ' + contact.lastName}}
                        {{contact.emailAddress}}</span>
                </span>
                                     <button class="btn editContact" data-ng-click="deleteContact(contact.id)">Delete</button>

                     <button class="btn editContact" data-ng-click="editContact(contact.id)">Edit</button>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is index.cshtml file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="contactsManager">
<head>
    <title>Contacts</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-top">
        <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="~/Content/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <h2>Contacts</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-view class="example-animate-container"
         ng-animate="{enter: 'example-enter', leave: 'example-leave'}"></div>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/application/application.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/application/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/application/contactsService.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it says line 4th of your controllers.js if you click on consol it should show you exact code.

Comment: @AnshulNigam I clicked on line that produce error but that didn't helped me. I edited my original code with comment where error triggers (on what line). But I don't know why it triggers there and  how to fix it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of arguments in the controller function has to match the order in the parameter array.

You have mixed the order of `$http` and `$location`.

So change your function signature to

```
app.controller('ContactsController', [
    '$scope', '$http', '$location', 'contactsService',
    function ($scope, $http, $location, contactsService) {
```

Comment: Thank you @nemesv . your suggestion is working perfectly. Now I have a problem that I got empty results from database. Since it's other type of problem I will mark your answer as a correect one (after minute mark)